# How to use only the last bit provided by this for loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

So, I'm trying to calculate a list of number to eventually sort, so I only want the final result of this for loop.

```
   for (int anno=startyear; TimePeriod>=anno;anno++) {
      System.out.println(anno);
   }
```

Where anno = 1995 and I am counting to the current day, I end up getting a result that slowly counts up, where it first counts at 1995, then it counts 1995 and then 1996, and so on.

How do I only get the end result for use in my program? The result that would simply be 1995-2014. Not the repeats.

edit: Forgot to mention I need every number in between 1995-2014 as well

Comment: In such case you don't need the loop. Just use `TimePeriod`.

Comment: You say you need every number in between, but you also only want the end result. What does that mean? What do you want, specifically?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need a loop for this, assuming your TimePeriod variable equals 2014 then just do the following to print out the desired result:

```
System.out.println(startyear+"-"+TimePeriod);
```

That will print out:

1995-2014

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I need every number in between as well

Comment: @nextDouble nobody will do you homework. try to google it. your question is kind of funny to ask cuz even my mother knows about concatenation

Answer (score 0):

You already know the final value: it's `TimePeriod`. If that's all you need, just use that and get rid of the loop:

```
System.out.printf("%d-%d", startyear, TimePeriod);
```